# Do you need to state that you have written permission from the copyright holder of the image I use as cover

Tags: thesis, copyright

I am using a picture for the cover of my thesis. I received written permission from the copyright holder of this picture that I may use it for this purpose.

Do I need to make a comment somewhere in my thesis that I have this written permission and if so, where shall I make this comment? Or do even I need to include the entire written permission, perhaps in an appendix.

Answer (score 3):

It is common in book length material to give a citation of the photo, perhaps in a footnote. The title page, if present, or a page just following, is possible. So is a footnote on the last page, which is probably a list of references. Another possibility is on an "Acknowledgements" page, if present.Just mark the citation for the photo as "used with permission".

The citation is necessary in any case since the work isn't yours.

It isn't necessary to include the entire permission statement. But keep a copy of the statement.